# How to: concatenate a php array generated from a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am working on a player name generator using MYSQL/PHP. How do I select the values of a one column (not including primary key) table into a one-dimensional array and then concatenate the values of the array?

example table 'syllableInitials':

```
characters
t
d
ch
```

php code

```
$syllable = array("","","");

$sql = "SELECT characters FROM syllableInitials";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$syllableInitials = array();

while ($initial = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $syllableInitials[] = $initial;
}
$syllableMedials = array("a", "o", "i");
$syllableFinals = array("m","s","d");

$syllable[0] = $syllableInitials[0] . $syllableMedials[2] . $syllableFinals[0];

echo "Syllable is: <b>" . $syllable[0] . "</b>";
```

Output I get is:

***Notice: Array to string conversion in line...
Syllable is: Arrayim***

Obviously, my intended output for the above example code would be "tim" not "Arrayim".

A **print_r** for the syllableInitials array generates this...

```
Array (
     [0] => Array ( [0] => t )
     [1] => Array ( [0] => d ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => ch )
)
```

So it looks like somehow I am inadvertently nesting the array or causing it to be two-dimensional! My coding is real rusty... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $initial is an array and has one element you can do:

```
$syllableInitials[] = $initial[0];
```

But a better solution would be to use PDO with its [PDOStatement::fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) function.

For example:

```
$syllable = array("","","");

$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password', $options);

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT characters FROM syllableInitials');
$sth->execute();

$syllableInitials = array();

while ($initial = $sth->fetchColumn()) {
    $syllableInitials[] = $initial;
}
$syllableMedials = array("a", "o", "i");
$syllableFinals = array("m","s","d");

$syllable[0] = $syllableInitials[0] . $syllableMedials[2] . $syllableFinals[0];

echo "Syllable is: <b>" . $syllable[0] . "</b>";
```

Comment: Changing $initial to $initial[0] inside the while loop did it - thank you @ankabout! ( I'm already using mysqli otherwise would try fetchColumn() ... )

Answer (score 0):

This should give you "tim":

```
$syllable[0] = $syllableInitials[0][0] . $syllableMedials[2] . $syllableFinals[0];
```

In your code you are only pointing to an other array inside [0];

```
Array (
     [0] => **Array ( [0] => t )**
     [1] => Array ( [0] => d ) 
     [2] => Array ( [0] => ch )
)
```

So your have two options..

**First:**

```
$syllable = array("","","");

$sql = "SELECT characters FROM syllableInitials";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$syllableInitials = array();

while ($initial = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $syllableInitials[] = $initial[0];
}
$syllableMedials = array("a", "o", "i");
$syllableFinals = array("m","s","d");

$syllable[0] = $syllableInitials[0] . $syllableMedials[2] . $syllableFinals[0];

echo "Syllable is: <b>" . $syllable[0] . "</b>";
```

**Second:**

```
$syllable = array("","","");

$sql = "SELECT characters FROM syllableInitials";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$syllableInitials = array();

while ($initial = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $syllableInitials[] = $initial;
}
$syllableMedials = array("a", "o", "i");
$syllableFinals = array("m","s","d");

$syllable[0] = $syllableInitials[0][0] . $syllableMedials[2] . $syllableFinals[0];

echo "Syllable is: <b>" . $syllable[0] . "</b>";
```

Comment: but if i just want a one-dimensional array from a single-column table, why deal with nested / multidimensional arrays at all?

Comment: Avoiding that would be the best.